# 301 redirect for weird 404 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having this 404 errors alerts in my Wordpress install:

> http://www.example.org/page/example.org

I'm trying to solve this with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://example.org/^/example.org(.*)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want to strip the last "example.org" so the 301 redirects to

http://www.example.org/page/

But it is not working, am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance

---

### Update:

I'm trying to replicate the rule to react to another case, and I went too far in the comments section with mr anubhava, here is what I'm trying to do:

If the request URL looks like **example.com/[page]/example.com**, it should be redirected to **example.com/[page]/**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/example\.com /$1/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

This rule works just fine, but in another case, if the requested URL is **example.com/[page]/example.com.mx** the redirect should go to **example.com.mx/[page]/**

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(example\.com\.mx)/?$ http://$2/$1/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

Looks like this rule should work, but it does not. Any clue?

Comment: http_host contains JUST the hostname. it doesn't have the rest of the url. You'd need to test `%{REQUEST_URI} ^example.org` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as **your very first rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/example\.org/?$ /$1/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I now understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: hey anubhava,
I'm trying to make this work also like this:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\.mx$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/example\.com\.mx/?$ /$1/ [NC,L,R=301]

Being {HTTP_HOST} example.com, I want to redirect the example.com.mx to example.com.mx/page/

It did not work.

Comment: when the URL is like http://www.example.com/page/example.com.mx I try to redirect to http://www.example.com.mx/page/ instead of http://www.example.com/page/.

The solution you gave me works for the first case, but this case also happens, I supposed I would be able to figure out the second case with the solution to the first one.

Comment: I did not explain myself well enough:
When the requested url is example.com/page/example.com I need to redirect it to example.com/page/. This is perfectly done with you rule, thanks.
But when the requested url is example.com/page/example.com.mx I need to redirect it to example.com.mx/page/ instead.

Comment: ok then add a new rule: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(example\.com\.mx)/?$ http://$2/$1/ [NC,L,R=301]`

Comment: So far I'm here: 
               
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\.mx$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(example\.com\.mx)/?$ http://$2/$1/ [NC,L,R=301]
             
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/example\. /$1/ [NC,L,R=301]

Only the .com redirection is working.

Comment: It should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]` for 1st rule as you request is `example.com/page/example.com.mx` NOT `example.com.mx/page/example.com.mx`